# Eclipse points to the wrong path in dependencies

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dependencies, buildpath

I have an Android Application project in Eclipse, and for nth time I have this annoying error. I create a new blank project which references android-support-v7-appcompat library. The JAR files of this library are located at

```
android-support-v7-appcompat\libs.
```

However Eclipse insists, that they are in

```
android-support-v7-appcompat\bin, and the result is as follows:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho7qN.png

What the hell is going on here? The support library is installed, there is nothing else that this project is referencing, all should be fine. Any ideas?

Comment: can you use android-studio?

Comment: no, I can't. I mean I could, but I'm really short on time, and I can't waste it on configuring the new environment. plus I got tons of purely Java projects anyway, so I need to get them up and running too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be having appcompat project in project explorer. expand bin folder of that project and check whether it has appcompat_v7.jar in it. If not then clean and build the project.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be the solution is :

Either update the config file where the preferred path is as  android-support-v7-appcompat\bin ,

or else do not paste lib files in android-support-v7-appcompat\libs , instead put them in bin directory .

still , let me check why else this issue can come , will post in this thread.